# Swiper not attached to any scroll views

Tags: flutter, swiper.js

I write swiper.And i have Exception ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.I dont know how to solve this.

return Swiper(

```
                loop: true,
                autoplay: false,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return _itemList(snapshot.data[index], context, index);
                },
                viewportFraction: 0.8,
                scale: 0.7            
                index: 0,
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `index: 0` and it should work.

Background info: passing an `index` value causes the error and it looks like it is caused in a dependency library of swiper called `transformer_page_view` or a wrong implementation in swiper.

Since I also had the same problem and did not find any solution on the web, I will share my code on how to set the initial `index` value:

```
  final _controller = SwiperController();
  // "animation: false" does the trick
  // "index" is the initial value when the swiper is shown
  _controller.move(index, animation: false);
  // ...
  return Swiper(
    controller: _controller, /* ... */
  );
```

After the swiper is mounted you can change the index with animation:

```
  _controller.move(newIndex);
```